# Memory consumption in C

Tags: c, memory, struct

I would like to know how to measure the memory consumption of a graph in C.
With the following Code I initialize a Graph with V nodes and no Edges:

```
Graph GRAPHinit(int V)
{ 
    int v;
    Graph G = malloc(sizeof *G);
    G->V = V; G->E = 0;
    G->adj = malloc(V*sizeof(link));
    for (v = 0; v < V; v++) G->adj[v] = NULL;

    return G;
}
```

The Graph is a struct, represented as a adjacency list:

```
struct graph { 
    int V; 
    int E; 
    link *adj; 
};

typedef struct node *link; 

struct node {
    int v; 
    link next; 
};

typedef struct graph *Graph
```

Is it possible to measure the amount of space G uses with the sizeof-Operator?
Other possibilities?

Comment: Does this code actually compile?

Comment: @Lefteris no it did not.

Comment: I assume it's missing a `typedef struct graph *Graph`. @PaulP.R.O. yes you can, and it's *very* useful. `sizeof` is a compiletime construct (ignoring VLAs), it simply evaluated to the size of the type `G` points to.

Comment: @delnan Ah cool, good to now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do it purely with the sizeof-operator as this can only be used for compile-time, static memory allocations.

At best you can implement a new function like

```
unsigned int getMemoryUsage(Graph *g){ 
    return sizeof(*G) + G->V * sizeof(link);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to measure:

a) memory `malloc`ed by this graph
b) program memory consumption due to allocating a graph

For a), just count up the number of each kind of node and multiply by the sizeofs of each type.  For b), you could compute a) and then look at the implementation of `malloc()` to see what it does behind the scenes.  There are other techniques, such as [black box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) strategies which tend to require a lot of effort to validate.

Answer (score 0):

G is 2 integers and a pointer.
Each struct the pointer points at contains an `int` and another pointer.
In 32-bit land, 12 bytes for G and 8 bytes for each link.  That does not count the extra overhead that each `malloc()` entails, nor the fact that `malloc()` does not in fact have to allocate such small chunks of memory for each struct.

Short answer, you need to measure this yourself or allocate with your own special allocator from a pool if you want exact sizes.